# Spring integration - save complete message to database and read it again

Tags: json, serialization, spring-integration, spring-amqp

Is there possibility to serialize full Message to some format e.g. JSON and save it to db. After this I would deserialize the message with full headers and send it to amqp. Something like:

```
<int:object-to-json-transformer object-mapper="mapper" />
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter channel="srk2" data-source="dataSource" query="insert into messages (serialized_message) values (:message_with_headers)" />
```

and then

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="SELECT auto_inc_id,serialized_message FROM messages" channel="oc" data-source="dataSource">
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter exchange-name="bookmakers" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" channel="oc" order="1" />
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter channel="oc" data-source="dataSource" query="DELETE FROM messages WHERE auto_incr_id IN (:auto_inc_id)" order="2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Look you can do that exactly with the `<int:object-to-json-transformer>` or any other similar transformer. But you have to place in front of it this trick:

```
<service-activator expression="T(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder).withPayload(#root)"/>
```

Just because the first one does conversion only for the `payload`. So, to store headers as well you have to place whole message to the `payload`.

There is other component on the matter - `<claim-check>` which definitely stores the whole message in the DB: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#claim-check

Comment: Thanks. Claim check seems like the thing i needed and obviously wanted to re-invent :)

Comment: How claim-check knows where to send the saved message in case that thread that saved message fails? Can claim-check-out work as poller on separate thread?

Comment: Sorry, that isn't clear. Please start a new SO thread with more background

Comment: Just tried to put this before object-to-json-transformer but still in :payload I have only actual payload without headers... You sure this will work?

Comment: I probably bored you with this... but tried the thing with the #root - to put this before object-to-json-transformer but still no luck. Did some debugging and think that problem is in AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer in line `if (result instanceof Message<?>) {
   return (Message<?>) result;
  }
  return getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(result).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).build();` Since result is always instance of Message it never goes to last statement.

Comment: Sorry for delay and thank you for one more reminder. How do you mean that it doesn't work? Share some stack trace on the matter

Comment: Well, if I have this setup: `<int:chain input-channel="output-channel" order="1">
        <int:transformer expression="#root" />
        <int:object-to-json-transformer object-mapper="mapper" />
        <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter data-source="dataSource"
                query="INSERT INTO int_message(MESSAGE_ID, REGION, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_BYTES) VALUES (9999,FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *60 ),NOW(),:payload)" />
    </int:chain>`, :payload is still just body of the message without headers beeing serialized together to json.

Comment: Sorry, after testing I can confirm that `<transformer>` solution is wrong. Please, find in my answer a `<service-activator>`